# Edit button not working for the first entry in the HTML table

Tags: php, html

I am creating an admin dashboard where someone can create user accounts and then edit and delete credentials. I created an edit button next to each user in a table which when clicked will show their id but the button works properly for the second and third user but not the first one, even tho its the same code in doing loop.

I tried deleting the first entry using PHPMyAdmin but then the previous second user who now first has the same issue. I went through the code again to make sure everything is the same and it's not happening because I forgot to close off a table or so.

```
<div class="card-body">
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success'] !='')
        {
            echo '<h2>'.$_SESSION['success'].'</h2>';
            unset($_SESSION['success']);
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        include ('includes/dbh.inc.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn,$query)
        ?>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">User ID</th>
                <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">EDIT</th>
                <th scope="col">DELETE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                    {
                        ?>




                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['idUsers'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['uidUsers'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['emailUsers'];?></td>
                <td>
                    <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $row['idUsers'];?>">
                    <button type="submit" name="edit_btn" class="btn btn-success">EDIT</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php

                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo "No Record Found";
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

     if (empty($username)||empty($email)||empty($password)||empty($passwordRepeat)){
         header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
     }
     elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
         exit();
     }
     elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
         header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
         exit();
     }
     elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
         header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
         exit();
     }
     elseif ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
         header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheckuid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    else {

        $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? ";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit(); 
        }
        else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
                exit();
            }
            else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers,pwdUsers) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss" ,$username,$email,$hashedPwd);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    header("Location:/signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();

                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);

 }

 else {
      header("Location ../signupp.php");
      exit();
 }
```

I would like to know the mistake I made and if there is a better way to implement this

Comment: You can check with the chrome developer tools (if you're using chrome) what the value of the first row is. Check this first.

Comment: @thmspl I checked the value and it is showing the expected value which is the id of the user.

Comment: maybe there is problem within this file includes/signup.inc.php

Comment: Whats the id for the first user? Why are you creating a form element for every entry? Just use a link tag like this: `<a href="includes/signup.inc.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['idUsers'];?>">Edit</a>`. This would be way better.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli that is the PHP file for which I have posted the code above

Comment: @thmspl can you explain how the code you provided is better? I am making this by watching a youtube tutorial and he used this method. I am pretty new in backend coding so if you can explain it would be very helpful.

Comment: provide me this file  include ('includes/dbh.inc.php');

Comment: I used the same file includes/signup.inc.php for testing maybe there is some different code in above file which is conflicting.

Comment: the dbh includes file has the code to init connection with the database I have combined codes from 2 PHP files and submitted above as I thought they were the only relevant ones.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in the code...

I tested it by setting it up on my system. below are the screenshots.

[image]

I am getting the right id in the console.

after clicking on submit I am getting the correct id as output from PHP

[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying this. If the code is working for you it maybe something is not right with the rest of the code. I will go through my code and try to update you